# HTML Living Standard just removed application cache related code/documentation. Does this mean it got deprecated completely?

Tags: html, html5-appcache, application-cache

Title says most of it. Until today it was possible to see application cache related documentation in https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#applicationcache

Now, the page doesn't show anything related to application cache. Does this mean it got completely deprecated?

Is there a way to find the old documentation? Will old browsers like Edge not be able to support Application Cache any more even though they supported it until yesterday?

Removal commit: https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/e4330d510a1d05e1f5f84707c9d6dcec97db94b8

Comment: I found that you can find the old documentation by looking at a snapshot. For example: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/commit-snapshots/27ca698a224a4fcf59b647be80a0c86c3c6abba5/#appcacheevents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes it's deprecated. It's already been removed from Chrome and Firefox since a few versions in non secure contexts and will be soon in any context in all major browsers.
- You already found an [old version of the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/commit-snapshots/27ca698a224a4fcf59b647be80a0c86c3c6abba5/#appcacheevents) but this is not the "documentation", it is the rules for implementers, and don't require keeping deprecated features in there. User-docs are still [available on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)
- No old browser won't stop doing what they've been written to do magically because someone changed the text of whatwg website.